# OpenCV face detection methods hangs

Tags: python, opencv

I have used OpenCVs detectMultiScale and res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel.forward() methods to detect faces in the images. Exact code is shown.

Both these methods worked well providing good results until a day ago. Today, both of these processes hangs at detectMultiScale and net.forward commands respectively. Additionally when the DNN based model runs, the system memory slowly starts building up until the system hangs.

There has been no modification in any of the python libraries or system configuration in the last day. I have tried to reinstall openCV and python so far which has not been benificial.

```
#code for For cascade based detection:
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frame)

#Python code for For DNN based detection:
modelFile = "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
configFile = "deploy.prototxt"
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(configFile, modelFile)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

I am unable to understand the reason behind the memory leak that is happening and possible solution to overcome this.